# Unable to create outlook calendar event

Tags: c#, asp.net, kentico

I want to create event in outlook calendar.i did poc .it is working fine.when ever it is used in my project it is not working . I am not able to create calendar event. Any help is appreciated

```
 _Application olApp = (_Application)new Application();
 'NameSpace mapiNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
 string profile = "";
 mapiNS.Logon(profile, null, null, null);


 _AppointmentItem apt = (_AppointmentItem)
 olApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
 // set some properties
 apt.Subject = "Test";
 apt.Body = "Testing body";
 apt.Start = new DateTime(2017, 5, 20, 13, 30, 00);
 apt.End = new DateTime(2017, 5, 20, 14, 30, 00);
 apt.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15;        // One week
 apt.BusyStatus = OlBusyStatus.olTentative;  // Makes it appear bold in the calendar - which I like!
 apt.AllDayEvent = false;
 apt.Location = "Hyderabad";


 bool res=apt.ForceUpdateToAllAttendees;
 apt.Save();
```

//when i am using in project

```
_public bool CreateOutlookCalendarEvent(EventContent objEvent) {
        try
        {
            Application olApp = (_Application)new Application();
            NameSpace mapiNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            string profile = "";
            mapiNS.Logon(profile, null, null, null);
           _AppointmentItem apt = (_AppointmentItem)
                    olApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
            // set some properties
            apt.Subject = objEvent.EventName;
            apt.Body = objEvent.EventDescription;

            apt.Start = objEvent.EventStartDate;
            apt.End = objEvent.EventEndDate;
            apt.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15;        // One week
            apt.BusyStatus = OlBusyStatus.olTentative;  // Makes it appear bold in the calendar - which I like!
            apt.AllDayEvent = false;
            apt.Location = objEvent.EventAddress;


            bool res = apt.ForceUpdateToAllAttendees;
            apt.Save();
            objEvent.EntryID = Convert.ToInt32(apt.EntryID);

            // Prepare the parameters
            string customTableClassName = "customtable.OutlookCalendar";

            // Check if Custom table 'Sample table' exists
            DataClassInfo customTable = DataClassInfoProvider.GetDataClassInfo(customTableClassName);
            if (customTable != null)
            {
                // Create new custom table item 
                CustomTableItem newCustomTableItem = CustomTableItem.New(customTableClassName);

                // Set the ItemText field value
                newCustomTableItem.SetValue("EventID", objEvent.EventID);
                newCustomTableItem.SetValue("EventName", objEvent.EventName);

                newCustomTableItem.SetValue("EventDescription", objEvent.EventDescription);
                newCustomTableItem.SetValue("EventStartDate", objEvent.EventStartDate);
                newCustomTableItem.SetValue("EventEndDate", objEvent.EventEndDate);
                newCustomTableItem.SetValue("EventAddress", objEvent.EventAddress);

                newCustomTableItem.SetValue("Recivier", objEvent.Recivier);
                newCustomTableItem.SetValue("EntryID", "New text");
                // Insert the custom table item into database
                newCustomTableItem.Insert();

                return true;
            }

            return false;

        }
```

Comment: Can you explain what isn't working?  is the insert to the new custom table item not working? Or trying to figure out how to convert the custom table item into a calendar event file that outlook can consume?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this the quick way, check out my Webpart to API converter, in it, it has instructions on how to create an outlook event feed so they can save events to outlook.  It includes all the transformations and supporting code (just make sure to include code files and global folders when you import it).

https://devnet.kentico.com/marketplace/web-parts/webpart-to-api-converter

It's used on pages like this:
http://www.ecasd.us/District/About/Events/2016-2017-School-Year-Calendar/Board-of-Education-Meeting-(16)

1. Click "Subscribe to this Search with your personal calendar"
2. Click "Download iCal file" on the bottom of the pop up